# jQuery "dialog" error caused by "Script Manager"

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my case (VS2013, Win8, ie10) I am using

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and the jQuery dialog is working properly.

The problem appears with adding a "Script Manager" (on my "aspx" page). Immediately I get a message:

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

It seems like the Script Manager loads the same libraries, but on the other side, without these scripts the project does not work too.

Comment: Switch the tags around

Comment: Make sure your IE10 is not in quirks mode or trying to emulate an older version of IE, as JQuery 2.0+ is only meant for modern browsers and will not work on older versions of IE.

Comment: I checked with other browsers (Firefox and Google Chrome) - the same story: without the Script Manager it works, but with it - does not.